# DropDownList Custom CSS Skin

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css

I've got two problems with skinning this dropdownlist in Chrome the text doesn't vertically align in the middle and the other problem is in IE10 when you click the dropdownlist the list goes over the dropdownlist instead of going underneath it and also the select list has a horrible black border around it in IE10 does anyone know how to fix these problems - copy and paste the code below and have a look at what I mean.

```
select::-ms-expand{
    display: none;
}

select:focus
{
    border-color: #139fe0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
             border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(85, 190, 239, .75);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(85, 190, 239, .75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(85, 190, 239, .75);
}

select {
    outline : none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 2px;  
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-image: url(images/dropdown_arrow.png);
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    color: #555;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


<select>
    <option value="yourMom">Your Mom</option>
    <option value="myMom">My Mom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which version/s of IE? For the benefit of those answering your question could your update your question with this link http://jsfiddle.net/v4YpV/.

Comment: I got the vertical alignment right for IE10 and Mozilla